# Weight of asset has to be smaller than b% in the portfolio(Portfolio Optimization)

Tags: portfolio-optimization

Given a certain portfolio with y assets, calculate the weight of each asset in the portfolio based on the asset position.

The weight for each asset is calculated by (yn is the position of a certain asset in the portolio):

[image]

And the restrictions for the weights are:
The sum of the weights is equal to 1

[image]

All weights have to be smaller than a certain percentage 'b'

[image]

The question here is, is there any classical algortihm that adjusts the position of the assets so the weight is always smaller than b?
My strategy would be decrease the position by a fix value until everyone is smaller than b

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Could you please describe your primary goal here? Do you want to implement something yourself, are you looking for software, are you looking for algorithms?

Comment: Hi, assuming that you are basing your question on a mean-variance-portfolio-optimization problem, you would be looking for an implementation of the `Quadratic Programming` algorithm. There are various implementations available, e.g. in Excel's solver, Python or R.

Comment: Hi, my primary goal is to find the positions of each asset so the weight in potfolio is smaller than 'b'. Thanks for the suggestion, i'm going to search about this algorithm!

Comment: I read about this algorithm, but I don't want to minimize a function using some constraints. What I want is a method to decrease the position of assets in a portfolio so thw weight is not bigger than b, perhaps it is a numerical calculus problem.

Comment: Many indexes have "capping rules" like this see for example Page 9 of this document by FTSE Russell (an index provider). It is a simple iterative process that cycles through all the securities. https://research.ftserussell.com/products/downloads/Capping_Methodology_Guide.pdf

Comment: This question is already answered here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/39818/algorithm-for-calculating-capped-index-weightings

Comment: OK, if there's no optimization to be done then @noob2 's comment is probably the way to go.